# Hadoop : how to save web log to a local file?

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn

I want to know if it's possible to save the hadoop (yarn) web log for a job (container) to local file ? Now I can check all the log in browser but when the log is too long, my browser crashes. And I have no access to datalake. What is the best way to save the web log to a file that I can analyse locally ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `yarn logs -applicationId` command, with shell redirection to output to a file

Or you can SCP the file out of the nodemanagers where the code ran

Better solutions include setting up log collectors such Fluentd or Filebeat to stream the logs into Elasticsearch where they can be analyzed